# How to colour scatter points and create legend entries based on a data type column

Tags: tikz-pgf

Say I have a file like this:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots,filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{data}
1 10 type1
2 25 type2
3 75 type2
4 100 type3
5 150 type3
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}  

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}   
    \addplot[scatter,only marks] 
        table[row sep=crcr] {data};         
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

which produces this plot (noting that the code throws its toys out of the pram with the introduction of the third data column, and messes up plotting the (1,10) and (2,25) co-ordinates):

[image]

How do I:

1. Colour each scatter point, or perhaps assign each a random symbol, based on its "type" column. I realize the latter will probably need an "if type=type1, symbol=triangle" type statement, which is OK.
2. Create a legend to indicate which colour belongs to which data type

I can do this manually with separate `\addplot` commands for each data type followed by `\addlegendentry{type1}`, but surely there must be an easy way to automate this using a single `addplot`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In PGFPLOTS manual there is an example does exactly what you what. Currently it is at page 107, or **4.5.11 Scatter Plots**.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=9,tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[legend pos=south east]
    \addplot[
        scatter,only marks,scatter src=explicit symbolic,
        scatter/classes={
            a={mark=square*,blue},
            b={mark=triangle*,red},
            c={mark=o,draw=black,fill=black}
        }
    ]
    table[x=x,y=y,meta=label]{
        x    y    label
        0.1  0.15 a
        0.45 0.27 c
        0.02 0.17 a
        0.06 0.1  a
        0.9  0.5  b
        0.5  0.3  c
        0.85 0.52 b
        0.12 0.05 a
        0.73 0.45 b
        0.53 0.25 c
        0.76 0.5  b
        0.55 0.32 c
    };
    \legend{Class 1,Class 2,Class 3}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```